# How to get new posts from Telegram API with JavaScript

Tags: telegram

Is there a way to post the latest post from telegram channel to my website? I am working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [post widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets), but you will need to find a way to get the latest channel post by yourself: I would use a bot to track when the post is posted and store its ID in a database, then I would display it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can display any channel’s post when you enter last post link of a channel in the plugin’s Setting, but if you need to automatically show all new posts of your channel on TGchannel widget, you should add @TGCH_BOT to your telegram channel as admin.
This bot will refresh widget posts when a new post published in telegram channel. I don't know how exactly this could work, but I know that from a wordpress plugin.